# WCF wrapper service

Tags: wcf, wrapper, orchestration

We are planning to create a wrapper REST service in WCF with 2 or more WCF REST services under it (not exposed to client). This wrapper service just needs to call these individual services, combine their JSON response and send it back to the client. Is there any inbuilt framework I can use within WCF?

I want to avoid using BizTalk or any other third party framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the WCF Web HTTP programming model with the WebHttpBinding to do this. You can find docs on the programming model here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb412172(v=vs.100).aspx

That said, there isn't anything in WCF specifically aimed at your specific scenario; it would be just like any other service.

Another alternative implementation framework would be ASP.NET MVC WebAPI, which is now the preferred programming model for REST and HTTP-based services, as it provides a simpler programming model. You can find docs for this here: http://www.asp.net/web-api